# Installing Heroku Toolbelt on windows 7

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Im trying to deploy some project to heroku. 
I have installed heroku toolbelt for windows(im working on windows 7)
But when I input

```
heroku --version
```

in command line I get the following message

```
C:\Users\ЮРА>heroku --version
C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:164:in `spawn': No such file or di
rectory - open (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:164:in `background_up
date!'
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:144:in `inject_libpat
h'
        from C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It works only with windows user on latin
Look here https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/798

P.S. try to create new user with latin. Run heroku login from that user.